# Azure WebJob not timing out

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am running a triggered web job - runs on every 15 minutes - it is a console application which moves data from SQL Server to Mongo Database. I have configured the WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT and SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT values to 3600. It was in an idle state for the last 5 days and it didn't abort or timed out. I had to restart the web app to abort the web job and restart it.

[image: Azure WebJob Dashboard]

Is there a way I can configure the web job should abort after a specific time period?

Answer (score 1):

The `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` configuration only applies if your webjob has no CPU and no IO activity (see [WebJobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings) in the Kudu wiki)

CPU activity is measured via [Process.TotalProcessorTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime?view=netcore-3.1) while IO activity is measured via inspecting the standard and error output streams of your webjob for new characters. Source: [IdleManager.WaitForExit](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/a13592e6654585d5c2ee5c6a05fa39fa812ebb84/Kudu.Core/Infrastructure/IdleManager.cs#L43) and [Executable.ExecuteInternal](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/147c9b2890237c101b8ab7d48f0e83e89b7513f3/Kudu.Core/Infrastructure/Executable.cs#L175).

If possible, let your webjob exit gracefully after it's done its job. If you want to forcefully abort a long running operation that is still consuming CPU or IO, you'll have to code this in your webjob directly.